# Youtube Data API: order parameter

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Trying to order the results I get from Youtube's Data API by date but I get an error anytime I request anything but the default 'relevance' option.

```
... var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

var options = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: key,
    maxResults: 50,
    q: q,
    publishedAfter: "2018-06-09T00:00:00Z",
    safeSearch: 'none',
    order: 'relevance'
}  ...
```

There are the requests I'm using which works perfectly fine, only when I change relevance to 'date','rating' or any other option from the docs, the request fails.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working. I duplicated my request within Google's inbrowser API explorer and saw the sequence of parameters were a little different to my own so changed it to match.

So to clarify the sequence of parameters which works goes:

- snippet-maxResults-order-publishedAfter-q-safeSearch-key